# React initial renders null value but updates later. Need to set the value as initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-state

I have created a custom hook for storing the values the user selects in local storage.
The values are being stored in `localstorage`. I need the component to make use of the value returned by the custom hook and store it as the initial state when rendered. But the issue is the value returned when the component initially loads turns out to be `null`.
Due to this, the state is setting it to the `1` (i have handled it conditionally).

I need the updated value to somehow set the state even after the initial render is `null`.

Here is the code snippet

```
    const bedVal = useLocalStorage('beds')
    const bedroomsVal = useLocalStorage('bedrooms')
    const guestsVal = useLocalStorage('guests')
    const bathroomsVal = useLocalStorage('bathrooms')


    const [bedrooms, setBedrooms] = useState(bedroomsVal ? bedroomsVal : 1);
    const [beds, setBeds] = useState(bedVal ? bedVal : 1);
    const [guests, setGuests] = useState(guestsVal ? guestsVal : 1);
    const [bathrooms, setBathrooms] = useState(bathroomsVal ? bathroomsVal : 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the `useEffect` hook.

Something like that:

```
const [beds, setBeds] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
 setBeds(bedVal || 1);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ,that worked @NetanelVaknin . Just to add to your code, even though if we use `useEffect`  , the value is initially `null`, but if we add a dependency, it updates to the new value.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setBeds(bedVal || 1);
    }, [bedVal]);
```